# ASP.NET MVC5 access folder outside project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two ASP.NET MVC5 applications: A and B.
Both sites want to access a folder named C. This folder is outside these projects. So the folder structure is:

--**/root**

------**A** site files

------**B** site files

------**C** files wanted by both of the sites

(Folder C contains mostly images.)

So I want to display the images from folder C on site A and site B as well.

But if I set an img tag's source attribute to "/C/..." on site A, it means "/A/C/..." and of course, the file will not be found.

How could I reach my goal?

Thanks for help!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have site A as a Virtual Directory and site B as a Virtual Directory and both are in a web-application that is served as root for the domain. If that's the case, you can set the relative path to the root for resources like images like you mentioned.

Setting a root-relative path starting with / will work, since it will point to the root. But if you run your application A using it's own domain (so not under root's domain) using a root-relative path will point to the root of application A, not to site B.

You can test this by setting site A up as a virtual directory on your local IIS under the default web-application. Default web-application can be reached by http://localhost. If the virtual directory is called SiteA you can reach it with http://localhost/SiteA. If you use a roort-relative path starting with / it will always point to http://localhost. So in this setup you can reach any other location that's served under http://localhost and it's virtual directories, including SiteC (as a virtual directory).

Comment: Site A and site B use different domains. A is aaaa.com, B is bbbb.com. C is not a site application, but only is a folder that contains pictures used by both aaaa.com and bbbb.com sites. So imagine a ball.jpg picture in folder C (its full path is /C/ball.jpg on the server). And I want <img src="/C/ball.jpg" /> to display the ball.jpg picture properly, both on site A and site B.

Comment: I  think  C has to be hosted some where either on  a CDN or you have to host it on a domain say ccc.com and then you can probably hit an AJAX request to ccc.com from aaa.com or bbb.com to fetch these resources.

Comment: Yes, if a, b and c are different domains you have to use absolute urls to c. But then root mentioned in your example is not a root website, but just a root directory, which can't be used at all.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where the C folder is placed.
If it is placed outside the application A and B you can create another project as shared and include your C folder in this project and then add reference of this C folder in A and B individually.

Comment: C folder is next to A and B. So their parents are the same.

Comment: If it is just about accessing through folder within same root you can use relative path.
First come out of the current folder by  using ../ , say if you are in A folder and inside A folder you are in a folder with name  Pages like this

   -- A
        -- Pages(your current position)

use ../../  this will bring you out of Pages folder then it will bring you out of A folder then enter your C folder like this

         ../../A/C/Content/Images
../ helps you to step one step back from your current folder.
Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately this situation is not that simple.:( A and B use different domains, and C is outside both domains, so I can not address it relatively.